# Is there a non inline asm version of AngelScript?

Tags: c++, windows, x86-64, inline-assembly, angelscript

I recently worked a bit with [AngelScript](https://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/) and came across some linker errors when trying to compile in x64. If I try to compile my c++ code in x86 everything works fine. After a bit of research I noticed that inline assembly is not supported anymore by MSVC for x64.

Is there a AngelScript code version without the inline assembly so I can compile everything in x64?

Comment: Compilers other than MSVC have no problem with inline asm for ISAs other than 32-bit x86.  Have you tried with `clang-cl`?  Of course, that's not going to help unless the code you're building actually has 64-bit compatible inline asm.  Most inline asm for 32-bit assumes stuff like 32-bit pointers, and may take depend on things like leaving a return value in EAX and falling off the end of a non-void function, which MSVC supports by clang-cl doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. I think they will have to update their code to not use inline asm if there is a stable x64 bit version planned. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is outlined in the AngelScript [documentation](https://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/doc_compile_lib.html#doc_compile_win64); you basically have to add the as_callfunc_x64_msvc_asm file to the build for 64 bit.